# Missing Catch or Finally After Try

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Node, Express with EJS view engine, nano (for couchdb), and I'm running into this pretty puzzling error which I cold not find any Node/JS specific info about via SO or Goog. The area of my code that seems to be triggering this involves nested async callbacks which grab a document from CouchDB, look through it for some matches, and push an object to an array in my private scope.

And the error:

```
Express
500 SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try
at Object.Function (unknown source)
at exports.compile (/Users/Keith/Desktop/netPoetica/1- Projects/dcc-chargen/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:234:12)
at Object.exports.render (/Users/Keith/Desktop/netPoetica/1- Projects/dcc-chargen/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:273:10)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/Keith/Desktop/netPoetica/1- Projects/dcc-chargen/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:303:22)
at View.render (/Users/Keith/Desktop/netPoetica/1- Projects/dcc-chargen/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:75:8)
at Function.app.render (/Users/Keith/Desktop/netPoetica/1- Projects/dcc-chargen/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:501:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/Keith/Desktop/netPoetica/1- Projects/dcc-chargen/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:7)
at exports.dashboard.res.render.msg (/Users/Keith/Desktop/netPoetica/1- Projects/dcc-chargen/routes/index.js:19:29)
at module.exports.read (/Users/Keith/Desktop/netPoetica/1- Projects/dcc-chargen/api/Character.js:56:25)
at Request._callback (/Users/Keith/Desktop/netPoetica/1- Projects/dcc-chargen/node_modules/nano/nano.js:296:11)
```

Comment: That code is obviously not the source of that error, as the code doesn't have any `try` in it. Look *above* that code.

Comment: Hey TJ - it's hard to say you're correct. I think the error reporting is not quite accurate. Unless the library itself for EJS is unstable, I don't think that the problem is accurately portrayed by the error reporting.

Comment: How is the file with the nested callbacks called?

Comment: @Keith: No, it's perfectly clear. The code you're trying to parse, when parsed correctly, opens a `try` somewhere and then never follows it with a `catch` or `finally`. The code you've quoted *cannot* be the source of the error, because it doesn't do that. Yes, it can sometimes be tricky to find errors like this, you have to go hunting above where it's reported, but it's perfectly clear that the quoted code is not where the problem actually is.

Comment: I added it in the edit, it's called from app.js using app.get() and it references a function in a file called routes.js

Comment: @TJ: Would you recommend then that I experiment with using alternate versions of the library to test the stability of the build?

Comment: @Keith: (If you want @ notification to work, you have to spell the name correctly. Your best bet is to accept one of the suggestions the SO editor offers you. `@TJ` does not notify me.) There's nothing for it but to look at all of the code being parsed and find the dangling `try`.

Comment: @11684: Lines 19 and 29 are both calls to res.render(). If I take out the if block and direct the route to my second call (in the else block), the program works fine, which is why I sincerely doubt it's EJS, and more likely my inexperience with nested callbacks, but I will investigate the ejs file for said try

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the help and the tip - I'll check out the EJS lib and see if it's something there

Comment: Perhaps the syntax error is in res.render()?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error was a missing bracket on an if statement in my EJS template. As that trace shows, it was in the exports.compile function (which is called by res.render()) that this error occurs) - the lib author uses a string to create a new function, which encloses my EJS file functionality in a try block, which becomes a dangling try because my missing opening bracket in my if block caused a syntax error in the new anonymous function created as a string and built with "new Function('str')".

@T.J.Crowder pointed out, that stack trace is perfectly clear, and did ultimately lead to this solution. I removed some of my example code because it definitely wasn't linked to the ultimate problem.

Comment: Thanks. I found that I closed my final bracked with a "$>" rather than a "%>" which caused the error "SyntaxError: catch without try".

Answer (score 7):

For me it was a missing { on the below for loop caused the error. Look for proper closing or opening of paranthesis.

```
<% for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++) %>   
    <li> <%= users[i]   %>  </li>
    <%}%>
    </ul>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some "hello world" examples of this error.

### Scenario 1 (extra `,`)

Extra `,` between `try...catch` (From the habit of "if-else" syntax).

```js
/* Throw "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try" */
try {
  /* do something */
},catch (error) {
  /* do something */
}
```

[image]

**Valid code:**

```js
/* Valid code */
try {
 /* do something */
}
catch (error) {
 /* do something */
}
```

### Scenario 2

Use try without catch -or- finally.

```js
/* Throw error: Error: Missing catch or finally after try */
try {
  /* do something */
}
```

**MDN docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch